# Entire program Lost to null values

Tags: atom-editor

I had a program saved with the atom editor coded in Go. The last time I had edited it it was working fine, and i know i had saved it. But when I opened it today in like 3 different editors, all of the code turned into NULL values. The first editor was vim which made the NULL values look like "^@" When I opened it up in atom Nothing appeared. When I used Notepad++ it just showed "NULL" 4,159 times. If anyone had any ideas on this issue please let me know.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @Adrian ... "I just learned the importance of backups", I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is changed and you don't have a backup, there's nothing that Atom can do. Atom has [a long-running bug](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-crashed-and-my-source-file-ended-up-blank/16133/20) where crashes occasionally result in lost file information, but you don't mention a crash and the bug results in files being empty, not just unreadable. There's also no clear way, given the information you've provided, to figure out what caused the file to be changed, but it could be an encoding mixup. It's worth considering that the encoding metadata in the file could have gotten corrupted. You should try opening it in a few different encodings to see if that changes anything. [It sounds like](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reloading_a_file_using_a_different_encoding) that's pretty easy to do in vim.